# What can I do to get the system to accept my question?

Tags: discussion

why I was banned from facebook and I don’t see the stellar site? I am in blacklist, for what? I can not leave comments etc.can you help me?

Answer (score 2):

You have posted an identical question five times.  Four of these were deleted as they are duplicates of the first.  You should not keep reposting questions if you don't get an answer.

You cannot comment on questions over than your own yet as you haven't reached the required reputation.  I appreciate that this is frustrating.

You are not on any 'blacklist' at this site, we don't have them.  You are not suspended.

As for your position on Facebook, that is something to ask them, it is nothing to do with us.